# Why is ASGI labeled as "asynchronous" and WSGI as "synchronous"

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, wsgi, synchronous, asgi

I was researching this stuff for the first time and found the terminology to be confusing. A WSGI server handles one request at a time, and yet it is labeled as "synchronous" which means "happening at the same time". And on the other hand, ASGI servers can handle multiple requests at one time, and yet they are labeled as "asynchronous".
Thus, it would make sense to me that the labels would be switched...

Can anyone explain why it is defined this way?

Answer (score 0):

WSGI is tied closely to the traditional HTTP request/response cycle.  The WSGI server will receive a request, handle it and send a response.  This happens request by request (synchronously).

ASGI maintains an open connection until terminated.  Applications are called and awaited with a connection scope and two awaitable callables to receive event messages and send event messages back.  So communication can go back and forth while the socket is open (asynchronously).